# Delete nodes in linkedlist whose next node is greater

Tags: java, linked-list

> Given a singly linked list, remove all the nodes which have a greater
>   value on right side.
>
> Examples:
>
> a) The list 12->15->10->11->5->6->2->3->NULL should be changed to
>   15->11->6->3->NULL. Note that 12, 10, 5 and 2 have been deleted
>   because there is a greater value on the right side.
>
> When we examine 12, we see that after 12 there is one node with value
>   greater than 12 (i.e. 15), so we delete 12. When we examine 15, we
>   find no node after 15 that has value greater than 15 so we keep this
>   node. When we go like this, we get 15->6->3
>
> b) The list 10->20->30->40->50->60->NULL should be changed to
>   60->NULL. Note that 10, 20, 30, 40 and 50 have been deleted because
>   they all have a greater value on the right side.
>
> c) The list 60->50->40->30->20->10->NULL should not be changed.

This question is attributed to GeeksForGeeks.

Looking for code-review, optimizations and best practices

```
public class DeleteGreaterValueOnLeft {

    private Node first;
    private Node last;
    private int size;


    public DeleteGreaterValueOnLeft(List<Integer> items) {
        for (Integer item : items) {
            add (item);
        }
    }

    private void add (Integer item) {
        Node node = new Node(item);
        if (first == null) {
            first = last = node;
        } else {
            last.next = node;
            last = node;
        }
        size++;
    }

    public static class Node {
        private Node next;
        private int item;

        Node (int item) {
            this.item = item;
        }
    }



    public void deleteCurrentIfNextGreater() {
        reverse();
        delete();
        reverse();
    }


    private void reverse() {
        Node prev = null;
        Node ptr = first;
        Node ptrNext = null;

        while (ptr != null) {
            ptrNext = ptr.next;

            ptr.next = prev;

            prev = ptr;
            ptr = ptrNext;
        }

        first = prev;
    }


    private void delete () {
        Node ptr = first;

        while (ptr.next != null ) {
            if (ptr.item > ptr.next.item) {
                ptr.next = ptr.next.next;
            } else {
                ptr = ptr.next;
            }
        }
    }

    // size of new linkedlist is unknown to us, in such a case simply return the list rather than an array.
    public List<Integer> toList() {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        if (first == null) return list;

        for (Node x = first; x != null; x = x.next) {
            list.add(x.item);
        }

        return list;
    }


    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hashCode = 1;
        for (Node x = first; x != null; x = x.next)
            hashCode = 31*hashCode + (x == null ? 0 : x.hashCode());
        return hashCode;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        DeleteGreaterValueOnLeft other = (DeleteGreaterValueOnLeft) obj;
        Node currentListNode = first; 
        Node otherListNode =  other.first;

        while (currentListNode != null && otherListNode != null) {
            if (currentListNode.item != otherListNode.item) return false;
            currentListNode = currentListNode.next;
            otherListNode = otherListNode.next;
        }
        return currentListNode == null && otherListNode == null;
    }
}


public class DeleteGreaterValueOnLeftTest {

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        DeleteGreaterValueOnLeft dgvol1 = new DeleteGreaterValueOnLeft(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
        dgvol1.deleteCurrentIfNextGreater();
        assertEquals(new DeleteGreaterValueOnLeft(Arrays.asList(5)), dgvol1);
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        DeleteGreaterValueOnLeft dgvol2 = new DeleteGreaterValueOnLeft(Arrays.asList(5, 4, 3, 2, 1));
        dgvol2.deleteCurrentIfNextGreater();
        assertEquals(new DeleteGreaterValueOnLeft(Arrays.asList(5, 4, 3, 2, 1)), dgvol2);
    }

}
```

Comment: Question: Is the behaviour for a linked list: "12->15->10->16->5->2->3->NULL" defined? "on the right side" is a little unclear IMO. It could be either: "15->16->5->3->NULL" or "16->5->3->NULL", please clarify ;)

Answer (score 5):

Nice code. I'm assuming that you read Vogel612 comment and it is doing what you want it to do.

### Naming

- `ptrNext`, `ptr`, but then only `prev`? I would make this uniform.
  Probably: `next`, `current`, and `previous` (or `nextNode`,
  `currentNode`, and `previousNode` to avoid having `next` for two
  different things). I would also make sure that I follow the same pattern I choose here in the other methods.
- I would probably call the class SingleLinkedList or something like
  that.

### Errors

- In `reverse`: you do not change the `last` field
- In `delete`: here, you are not only not changing the `last` field,
  but also the `first` field, as well as the `size` field

### Optimizations

Traversing two times through the list to reverse it should be unneccessary. Just go forwards in the list, check if the next item is bigger, and - if so - set the previous nodes `next` field to the currents nodes `next` value (and handle it for `first` and `last` outside the loop).

### Other

- Your List implements `hashCode` and uses the `hashCode` method of the
  node class, but this class does not implement the method.
- You have the private `add` method but never use it. Unused private methods should probably be deleted.

### Tests

- Your test should definitely check all the examples from the question
  (although the two you have probably cover all cases).
- They should also check corner cases. Are `first` and `last` (and
  `size`) set correctly?

### Comments

You don't have to overdo it with comments, but just one seems a bit few.
Some comments that might be useful:

- Are the `first`, `last` and `size` field affected by the method?
  (should definitely be commented on in case the methods handle this
  differently, like in your case `add` and `delete` for example)
- `reverse`: a comment for what this does probably would not hurt